# How can I check if an element has any children elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that is floating left and the other floating right. I want to check if the div that is floating right has children element; if the it don't have any visible element, I want applied and new class to the left div. See below:

```
<div id="leftContent" class="left ">
    <table></table>
</div> 


<div id="rightContent" class="content">
    //the dom has no visible element
    //”#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ somegridView” is not visible     
</div>
```

And I’m using the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(“#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ somegridView”).lenght = 0) {

        $("# leftContent ").removeClass("left");
        $("# leftContent ").addClass("center");


    }
});
```

---

```
div.left
{
    float: left;
    width: 365px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
div.center
{
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: none;
    width: 95%;
    clear: both;
}
```

If `div id="rightContent"` empty?

Comment: Careful... `rightContent` does have children, but they are text nodes. Not sure if it's intentional, but `// ...` is a C style comment, and `<!-- ... -->` is a html comment.

Comment: rightContent text are comments.

Answer (score 13):

```
if ( $("#rightContent").children().length > 0)
{

   // do style changes

}
```

Comment: you can actually remove the "> 0" part...although it may make a bit less readable

Answer (score 11):

You can use [is](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/is) along with [:empty](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/empty).

```
if($('#rightContent').is(':empty')) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my first jqury function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($('#rightContent').children().length === 0) {
    //Whatever
}
```

**EDIT**: Correct ID

Comment: why do u compare with 3 equal sign like if ($('#rightContent').children().length === 0) why not 2 equal sign

Comment: @user750398: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators